# combining text and image in android

Tags: android

[image]hie all,

i was trying to implement the home screen in carousel view, and i am stuck in combining the application icon and the title with respect to it. i am able to show the applications icons but merging with the title is to be done. i was refering the following blog

[carouse](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx)

in the below diagram there is only application and are missing with title. i tried with layout inflater  but i am getting an error. that class cast exception . i this its because custom CarouselImageView class what i am using . but unable to solve it.. :(

thanks in advance
datta

Answer (score 0):

TextView has a property called drawable top.

Try converting your image to drawable and set to the top of textview.